# Discord.js manage roles with only id

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to code a discord.js bot. Right now i am working on a tempmute system but can't seem to find out a way of removing a role from a user with only 
their id to work with! I have searched around the interwebs but i couldn't seem to find anything that helped me.
ex. [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) and [An idiots guide](https://anidiotsguide_old.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/content/information/understanding-roles.html)

My code:

```
exports.run = (client, message, args, config) => { if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>[config.BotMaster].includes(r.name))) return message.reply("Du behöver en högre rank!");
const mysql = require('mysql');
const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.host,
    user: config.user,
    password: config.password,
    database: config.database
});

    let role = message.guild.roles.find("name", config.Muted);
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM TempMute WHERE Time<=" + Date.now() + ' AND Unmuted!="True"'
    con.query(sql, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows[i];
            var sql2 = "UPDATE TempMute SET Unmuted = 'True' WHERE Id = " + row.Id + ";";
            con.query(sql2, function (err, result) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                var Id = row.Name
                var unmute = client.fetchUser(Id)
                unmute.removeRole(role).catch(console.error);
            });
        };
    });
};
```

Error:

```
/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
    ^

TypeError: unmute.removeRole is not a function
at Query._callback (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/commands/rm.js:22:24)
at Query.Sequence.end (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
at Query.OkPacket (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:72:10)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
at Parser.write (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
at Protocol.write (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Documents/PinkBot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
at Socket.emit (events.js:160:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:12)
```

Comment: Is there an error? What's happening that's not what you're expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.fetchUser(id)` returns a promise, and from that promise you'll get a user.
You can't remove roles from users. You need a GuildMember to remove a role.
Instead of: `var unmute = client.fetchUser(Id)`, you'll need something like this:

```
message.guild.fetchMember(Id).then(guildMember => {
    guildMember.removeRole(role).catch(console.error);
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the message object?

Comment: You need to have a guild id. If you are using that for multiple servers, you'll need to save the guild id into the database.
When you have a guildID you can do: `client.guilds.get('123').fetchMember()`

Comment: It might be possible to find the guild from the user id (find all guilds where that user is) but if that user is on multiple servers, that might break